# How can I set expo-av to use in-call volume instead of media volume (Android)

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

I implemented a dialing tone in my app which plays out loud when a user is placing a call.
The problem is, on android the volume control can be completely minimal (0) but on IOS this doesn’t happen (0.1). *– these values are just illustrations.*

After much research, I found out about **in-call volume** and **media volume**, and it turns out that on my Android (Samsung S22 ultra), toggling the in-call volume does nothing but the media volume does.

I don’t want users to completely turn down the volume.

What/How can I set **expo-av** to use **In-Call volume** instead of **Media volume**?